# React Native Data

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I'm new to React Native and I can't find how to storage data.
For example, I want to make an app where the user need to add his school grades and this stay registered in order to see them in the future. How do I storage this? (In a database or in the device)
I do realize this is a noob question but I searched a lot and I can't find the answer.

Comment: Yes. You store it in a database or on the device, depending on your requirements. This has nothing to do with react at all, it is just a general application design question. If the data is to be shared with others, some central server needs to access it, etc. then you obviously need a server and a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `@react-native-community/async-storage` to store data in users device for authorization or other stuffs.

**Storing Data**

```js
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
    
const storeData = async () => {
      try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('your_key', 'stored value')
      } catch (e) {
        // saving error
      }
    }
```

**Reading Data**

```js
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('your_key')
        if(value !== null) {
          // value previously stored 
        }
      } catch(e) {
        // error reading value
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the file by importing the package.

```
import FileViewer from 'react-native-file-viewer';

const path = // absolute-path-to-my-local-file.
FileViewer.open(path)
.then(() => {
    // success
})
.catch(error => {
    // error
});
```